# How to remove previous back stack entry from FragmentManager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack, fragmentmanager

I have an activity in which I am switching fragments using following method:

```
public void setCurrentFragment(Fragment fragment) {
     FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_left_right_in, R.anim.slide_left_right_out, R.anim.slide_right_left_in, R.anim.slide_right_left_out);
     transaction.replace(R.id.contentFrameLayout, fragment, Integer.toString(fragmentId++));
     transaction.addToBackStack(Integer.toString(fragmentId));
     transaction.commit();
}
```

My navigation stack looks like this:

N-2 -> N-1 -> N

When certain fragment N is 'opened' I want previous one (N-1) to be removed from the backstack, so when I press 'back' I want N-2 fragment to be restored.

When I call FragmentManager.popBackStack(..) in N fragment it removes N and N-1 fragment.

I have tried to call popBackStack(..) in N-1 fragment right before switching to N fragment. But in that case N-2 fragment is resumed, and only after that N fragment is displayed.

My question is: is there any way to remove previous fragment from backstack without popping current fragment?

Comment: Did you got any solution for the same as I am also facing the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

use `public abstract void popBackStack (int id, int flags)` to back stack. Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)
for example `getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(fragmentId,0);`

Comment: I have already tried it, it removes my current fragment from backstack too. Documentation says: 'Pop all back stack states up to the one with the given identifier. '

Answer (score 0):

you can use alternate method with above one which will not use
**addToBackStack()** method and call directly **commit()**;